# How to convert text/xml response into application/json wso2 EI

Tags: rest, soap, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a soap service and I need to expose this service as a rest api in Wso2 EI, content type is text/xml, I tried with

> `<property name="messageType" value="application/json"
>   scope="axis2"/>`

in the outsequence, but it doesnt convert my response into a json. Can you please assist me on how to do it.

I tried this,

```
    <resource methods="POST">
      <inSequence>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
```

Comment: Do you send the 'Accept' header with the request? If so, what's the type?

Comment: I want to pass two header parameters, 1, SOAPAction, 2,Content-type:text/xml, how can i set inside the insequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work perfectly. A sample REST API configuration given below.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CheckREST" context="/samplerest">
   <resource methods="GET">
      <inSequence>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http uri-template="http://localhost:8280/services/sampleSOAPproxy"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

If not working, please mention the EI version you are using.

Comment: what should be the request headers? specially Conten-type

Comment: My EI version is 6.4.0.

Comment: I did not add any specific request headers. Since we have specified response header in the outSequence, we will get the JSON response only.

Comment: If, my soap service is validating content type text/xml header, how can i proceed

Comment: You can add Content-Type : text/xml in the request header when you are sending the SOAP request.

Comment: If i pass content-type: text/xml in the header it doesnt convert the response into json, receives as text/xml

Answer (score 2):

Reason for this is that WSO2 EI or ESB is developed in a manner where it responds to a SOAP request with a SOAP response by default. When you invoke the PROXY or API with SOAPAction and Content-Type: text/xml, EI understands this as a SOAP request and it'll respond with a SOAP response.

So if the client request is in SOAP-1.1 EI responds with a SOAP-1.1 response or if the client request is in SOAP-1.2 EI responds with a SOAP-1.2.

To bypass this behaviour they have provided an additional property as below.

```
<property name="IsClientDoingREST" scope="default" type="BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
```

So, before responding the client, properties should be set as below to get the expected behaviour of responding with a JSON.

```
<property name="IsClientDoingREST" scope="default" type="BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
```

This approach will help you to get the JSON response out of a SOAP request.